# flex 4 - why dispatchEvent triggering creationComplete recursively

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a custom component called shopView which is an MXML skinnable component. I have a controller class called ShopController which takes care of showing this component in popup, updating info shown in the component etc.

Now, I wanted to maniupate some of the subcomponents of this ShopView after it has been created from the controller **after** the ShopView is created (creationComplete() event)

So, I have attached an event listener which intern does some initialization process

```
   creationComplete="init(event)"
```

the init() function

```
        private function init(event:FlexEvent):void{
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            initMenus();
            initSlots();
            dispatchEvent(event);
        }
```

Attached another creation complete event from the controller class

```
     _shop.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE,onShopCreated);
```

***_shop** is the instance of ShopView*

Now, if you see the init() function, there I am stopping the event propagation, doing some initialization process and after that I am dispatching the event (for the shop controller do the rest of the job)

Now, this is crashing the app because the crationComplete event of the ShopView is recursively called. I was thinking the dispatchEvent will propagate to the other listerners but seems like it is propagating back to the same component.

**I have fixed it by removing the e.stopImmediatePropagation() and dispatchEvent(event) lines from the init() function. But I want to know why it is happening like this?**

Is it a known issue for the mxml/flex components? OR it is expected behavior?

Update: I am not doing same in .as as I said below. Got answer, basically its my stupidity :)

> because I have not seen this behavior when I write .as classes where I
>   stopevent propagation and dispatch the event based on business logic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've basically created a loop by doing this, it will keep trying to initialise your application. I agree with takteek, you shouldn't need to stop and then re dispatch creation complete. Your component should be added to the view stack by the time you hit init(), so setting properties on it should work fine.

Comment: Basically before you removed the afore mentioned code, you were dispatching the same event, from the same component listening for that event, and from the same function that just got triggered by that same event. Hence the infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

When you redispatch an existing event `dispatchEvent` automatically clones it (since you can't dispatch the same event twice.) This clears any propagation-related flags.

May I ask why you want to redispatch CREATION_COMPLETE in this situation anyway? Both handlers will function just fine without the two lines you removed.

Comment: i did it because, the current code doesnt make sense because it works exactly the same way without the stop and redispatch the event. But I added it because, in future I am going to write a code where the creation complete is not completed from my business perspective as it has calls to asynchronous functions and I will need to dispatch creation complete after I receive the response.

Comment: What you need to do is simply run your code during preInitialize and fire your own event when it is done and run your code from that. creationComplete has a specific meaning, and it's a bad idea to hijack thath.